# Dealing with concurrent writes and reads

Tags: java, concurrency

I am trying to access an embedded database (H2) where writes are high (10/sec, all are counters for events). And I need to read that data once in 1min or so. Once read, the counters should be reset.

I am trying to achieve this behavior (pseudo code):

```
//Writer thread
SELECT count FROM counters_db WHERE type="eventID1";
if count:
   count++;
   UPDATE counters_db SET count=count WHERE type="eventID1";
else:
   INSERT INTO counters_db(eventID, count) VALUES(1, "eventID1")

//Reader thread
DATA = SELECT * FROM counters_db;
TRUNCATE TABLE counters_db;
process(DATA) <--Do something with the data
```

Both threads are running in parallel.

The issues I see is:

1. The SELECT-UPDATE-INSERT paradigm in writer thread looks buggy to me. I can loose data if I TRUNCATE in reader thread if something was inserted and was not a part of select in reader thread.
2. I am sure there can be a better way to handle this data than updating counts and then truncating is to flush it away. Maybe just inserting values will work (i.e. a very simple logic in writer thread which just inserts) and the reader thread will know which rows to process (but how?). This approach also has a risk to creating a lot of records in the embedded database. How can I handle that?

What is the best way to approach this problem? I am missing something obvious?

Comment: try looking at `select for update` because this option is there in oracle and in DB2 there is an option for specifying write lock and all.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, (ignoring reader threads) you have an issue where 2 writer threads attempt to insert at the same time, losing data:

- Use a global lock for insertion of counters.
- Typically databases have a updateOrInsert style command that will do this for you.

For #2, you have a few options that I can think of:

- Use a lock (fine grained to each counter or however your database system allows atomic updates).
- Be prepared to lose some data.
- On the reading side you can note what the counter value is (and possibly write this back to the database), never reset the counter, and simply ignore the data < previous value.

Comment: If you are simply updating the value of count, why would it become huge? If this is an issue, you could purge the database after some set amount of time, but be prepared to lose some data if you do it lock-free.